Why do the aliens blow themselves up at the end of "The Mile-long Spaceship"?
In the classic Kate Wilhem story "The Mile-Long Spaceship" telepathic contact is achieved between a telepathic human on Earth and an aggressive alien race. The plot concerns the aliens' attempts to locate Earth in order to destroy it. Failing that, they destroy the titular ship and themselves.
The story can be read in the April 1957 Astounding here.
I don't understand why the aliens blow themselves up. This commentator didn't either but suggests it's because they feared Earth might locate them. It doesn't seem to me that the text supports that interpretation.
The story has been reprinted several times including a contemporary best-of-the-year anthology so clearly I'm missing something.
Why do the aliens blow themselves up?

https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v59n02_1957-04_Gorgon776/page/n77/mode/2up

It appears the telepathic human was, at the end, beginning to reverse-engineer the advanced technology of the alien ship, which would make humanity an existential threat to the conquerors.  To prevent this (since they couldn't stop him from appearing) they scuttle their ship.

It's in the second last paragraph:  Allan, instead of becoming interested in astronomy, has become interested in atomic engineering and has started to study the aliens' ship:

"He's here again!" The telepath had almost given up expecting the alien ever again. He kept his mind locked in the other’s as he recited as though from a book. "He's completely over his injury, working again, enrolled in night classes at the school in his town. He's studying atomic engineering. He's in the engine room now getting data for something they call a thesis."

It's clear from earlier in the story that the aliens believe themselves to be the only race worthy of being on top, and have conquered every race that might potentially be a threat to their power:

"The fact that the race has atomics is another reason we must find them." This would be the third planet using atomic energy. A young race, an unknown potential. They did not have interstellar travel now, but one hundred fifty years ago they didn't have atomic energy and already they had reached their neighbor planets. It had taken three times as long for the captain's people to achieve the same success. The captain remembered the one other race located in his time that had atomics. They were exploring space in ever widening circles. True they hadn't made any startling advances yet in weapons, they had found decisive bombs and lethal rays and gases unnecessary. But they had learned fast. They had resisted the invaders with cunning and skill. Their bravery had never been questioned, but in the end the aggressors had won.


Thanks! That cleared it up.
